# Data Driven Tests with Coded UI in Visual Studio 2015 Error with TFS and MTM

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, data-driven-tests, mtm

I am trying to run a data driven test with MTM on other machines using a CSV file to drive the tests for login.
I am receiving this error when I try to run the test:

> Error adding test case [343] to test run: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am able to run the tests on my machine through VS2015, the test controller through VS2015, and the target PC in VS2015, however when I try to run the test on another machine through MTM I am prompted with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this nuget to you solution: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework"

Basically the other machine doesn't have the tools.